# XCode - Linker failed

Tags: xcode

I have  been given an xcode project and I am trying to compile and getting the following error:

`ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking`

I have looked inside `\Pods` and there is a folder there called `AFNetworking`

I can't see what the issue is, or how to fix this. Can anyone guide me to how to fix this issue?

Comment: If it is swift you may have to include it in your bridging header. See [this link](http://www.davidebettio.com/use-afnetworking-with-swift/)

Comment: @simpleBob Thank you. I have opened the `xcodeprog` which is not compiling, but `xcworkspace` is compiling but can't run in the simulator>

Comment: your `xcworkspace` is probably not compiling correctly. After compiling hit `⌘`+`8` and click the Build element on top. See if there are any errors or warnings you were not aware of